# Crystal Reports and Visual Basic.net 2012 decimal numbers localization

Tags: .net, vb.net, crystal-reports

I'm using Visual Basic.net 2012. I have installed Crystal Reports. I am connecting on database through DataSet (Telerik). When I create a Crystal report, I get in for example the ZIP code field 
**1.000** instead of **1000** and inventory number **10.986** instead **10986**.

How do I get out thousand separator? The web application will run on a server and I cannot change local settings on my computer? This must be set in a way that will later enable it to run on server.

Thank you very much for your advice :)

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to change the database field or the dataset field to not allow decimals. I'm not familiar with Telerik, so I'm not much help there. In Crystal Reports you could create a formula that would remove the dot.

```
Replace({tableName.FieldName}, ".", "")
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for a quick reply. I have found another solution for my problem, maybe someone else will also find it useful:
1. in DataSet I had to change in the Fields Properties the Datatype from String to Double.
2. Then I opened Crystal Reports again and choose the ZIP code field and then Format Object. The Format Editor has now changed and I was presented with formatting options for number. There I have selected the desired printout view.
This solution worked best for me.